# Getting KeyError when using request.session['value'] in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-sessions

I am trying to write session and want to read session from another view function in django. I am using django 3.1.5. **Here is my views.py code, I set a session after user is logged in** `request.session['value'] = 'istiak'`

```
def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password =request.POST.get('password')          
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                request.session['value'] = 'istiak'
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')
        context = {}    
    return render(request, 'library_site/login.html')
```

***And In this view I tried to get this session data. Code->** `usern = request.session['value']`*

```
def bookprofile(request):
    usern = request.session['value']    
    return render(request, 'library_site/bookprofile.html')
```

***But I am getting error `KeyError: 'value'` . Here is full error***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "B:\django\Django_Project\Library\library\library_site\views.py", line 31, in bookprofile
    usern = request.session['value']
  File "C:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
KeyError: 'value'
```

Comment: You do have `SessionMiddleware` enabled?

Comment: I have to point out the fact that the `if user is not None` will always be True. the user is just anonymous. You might want to test for `if user.is_autenticated`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because you access a key in `session` that does not exist.

You might want to consider doing some modifications to your code:

1. `if user is not None` in your login view will always be `True`, it will only return an `AnonymousUser`.
2. It seems like you can access the `bookprofile` view without being logged in or having set the `session['value']` value previously. You can set a default value for this by replacing the `session['value']` by `session.get('value', 'defaultValueHere')`. The other option would be to restrict access the `bookprofile` view when not being logged in. You can achieve this by adding the decorator `@login_required` on your view:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def bookprofile(request):
  usern = request.session['value']    
  return render(request, 'library_site/bookprofile.html')
```

Comment: Yes. I solved by following your instruction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please mark this question as correct to close the topic. Thanks!